# asp.net,c#.net grid view footer problem

Tags: asp.net, footer

i have a gridview in web page

`<asp:GridView ID="grid_search" runat="server" >`

and it contains Footer for total value of Columns

i have a Column name Production value in Gridview

`prod_val nvarchar(50)`

for data bind i use the code behind

`protected void grid_search_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` 
    {
        `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)`
        {

```
        `tot_prodVal = tot_prodVal + Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);`
```

}
}

but it shows an error at debugging time that

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

plz give me solution..

Comment: pls show the markup of `prod_val` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned footer in your question, I am guessing you want to perform that operation in the footer. So your if condition should be

```
e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer
```

I guess because you are using DataRow in your condition, e.Row.Cells[2].Text doesn't really point to the field you want it to.

Comment: **In my (c#) asp.net websit, we allow users to id and password for login, and i want 
to view the active(online) users in another web page.**